# Prime numbers with consecutive primes as digits

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Let $N(k)$ denote the number made with the digits of the first $k$ prime numbers. Then, we have $N(1)=2$, $N(2)= 23$, $N(3) =235$, $N(4)=2357$, and so on.

As I noticed that $N(k)$ was some prime number for $k=\{1,2,4\}$, it seemed that there would be more values of $k$ such that $N(k)$ would be prime; however, I have checked up to $N(30)$, and all $N(k)$ are composite numbers excepting the values $k=\{1,2,4\}$.

I see no reason for this to happen indefinitely, but the initial numerical evidence suggest that the mentioned values could be the only values such that $N(k)$ is prime. I would appreciate any help checking for bigger values of $k$, as well as (if any) some possible explanation of why $N(k)$ is composite excepting the values mentioned.

Thanks!

Comment: We might also ask, in what bases other than $b=10$ are $2b+3$, $2b^2+3b+5$, and $2b^3+3b^2+5b+7$ all prime? (Multi-digit representations change things up, though.)

Comment: https://oeis.org/A069151
Next Prime is $k=128:$
https://oeis.org/A046035

Comment: @pietfermat thanks for the reference! Would you mind posting your comment as an answer to close the post? Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify : The next nuber would be $235711$ , right ? So we concatenate the first $n$ prime number in base $10$

Comment: These numbers are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smarandache%E2%80%93Wellin_number https://oeis.org/A069151 and
the next Prime is k=128: https://oeis.org/A046035

Comment: look also [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Smarandache-WellinPrime.html)

Comment: Some people complain about the base-dependency of such concepts , but I do not consider this counterargument to be convincing. What might be worth mentioning is that there is no known Smarandache prime (here the numbers $1$ to $n$ are concatencated, in base $10$ , not only the primes). There is no special reason for this and there well could be one , but it would have to be huge.

Comment: @JuanMoreno I do not think that an OEIS-link should be posted as an answer , a comment is enough. Also this could well be a duplicate. But I like such questions and therefore upvoted it.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your comments!